# How to I tell a Springdata-repository's delete method to not throw an exception if an entity does not exists?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am using SpringData's repository. If I try to delete an entity via an ID which does not exist or never existed it throws an exception. Since I do not want to check whether the entity exists before I delete it, it would be nice that it would fail silently. It would make it easier because the observable behavior is the same - after the call the entity does not exists anymore. Whether it has been deleted or never existed, I do not care.

Is there a way to modify default behavior of `delete(EntityId)` so it won't throw an exception, if entity does not exsist?

[Documentation of SpringData's delete](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#delete-java.lang.Iterable) says that it will throw an exception if an entity does not exist.

Comment: where in the docs it says that it will throw an exception? it only say if given id is null it will throw

Comment: you are right. Unfortunately I asked this question five years ago and I can not remember what my problem was. Maybe I wanted to say it throws an exception when entity (not entityId) is null it throws an error. Hopefully it does not confuse you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Updated Answer (after downvotes)**

My original answer (below) is actually wrong: my understanding of the question was influenced also by the missing reference to the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` in the official JavaDoc (as reported by Adrian Baker in his comment).

So a better solution to this issue could be the one suggested by Yamashiro Rion

```
if (repository.existsById(entityId)) {
    repository.deleteById(entityId);
}
```

or this one (without the `if`, but probably worse performing):

```
repository.findById(entityId)
    .map(repository::delete)
```

---

**Original (Wrong) Answer**

JavaDocs says that an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown if the provided argument (id, entity, `Iterable<T>`) is null and not *if entity does not exsits*.

If you need to avoid the `IllegalArgumentException` you could implement a custom delete method that checks `id != null`:

```
public void customDelete(ID id) {
    if(id != null){
        this.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Take a look to [this docs section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) if you don't know how to add *"Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories"*

Comment: Sorry for asking again. If I write my customRepository I still need the interface? Or can I make it an abstract class which implements Repository interface?

Comment: @EhmKah Yes you need to add an interface with your custom methods and implement them in a concrete class. The documentation is very clear about this. Take a look.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer targets the question about a non-existing entity? The provided ID param is presumably non-null, but there does not exist such an entity in the data store. How does this answer prevent the exception in that case?

Comment: Although its unfortunately not stated in the javadoc, the org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository implementation throws EmptyResultDataAccessException if the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: It makes no sense at all. I cannot understand why this is the right answer.

Answer (score 19):

A viable solution that requires less code is to add a new method to the repository interface like this:

```
// @Modifying is necessary depending on your version of Spring
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = ?1")
public void deleteById(IdPrimitiveType id);`
```

--> to be tested if this can used with JPQL instead of native SQL to allow more complex id types than the default ones (int, long, String, ...)

Comment: There is no need to make that a native Query, JPQL can do bulk delete.

Comment: Looks like this is the only valid answer, the rest has race conditions

Answer (score 12):

In your repository you shall define the method with return type `Integer`:

```java
Integer deleteMyEntityById(Long id);
```

If entity to delete doesn't exist, your method return 0 or 1 if the entity has been deleted.

Answer (score 7):

Very simple solution: adding `All` to the method name.

Use `void deleteAllById(ID id)` instead of `delete(ID) or deleteById(ID)`.

This method should be defined by yourself, it does not come from spring built in `CRUDRepository`.

> This solution works, but whether this is compliant with spring data specification, see the comments and judge it yourself.

Comment: This doesn't work. And the `deleteAllById` method requires a list

Comment: @PeterLustig it works, I'm using this everywhere in my company project. I think you didn't even try the code before commenting.

Comment: More info about how I use this solution: I create an interface called BaseDao<T, ID>, which extends Repository<T, ID>, annotate it with NoRepositoryBean, add a method "fun deleteAllById(id: ID)" to it, let XxxDao extends the BaseDao<Xxx, String>. If you don't want the BaseDao, just add this method to your concrete DAO interfaces. This is very simple and basic.

Comment: The question was already answered. Why should I provide another one? A method named `deleteAllById` which only deletes a single entity and takes a single ID is misleading in many ways. In addition you overload a method of the CrudRepository with a different behaviour. This solution wouldn't pass any code review. I would recommend to read Uncle Bob's Clean Code instead of going ham here over a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

With `JpaRepository` you can easily delete an entity if it exists. In this example `PostsRepository` extends `JpaRepository`:

```
if (postsRepository.existsById(postId)) {
    postsRepository.deleteById(postId);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the better answer, no usage of native queries, no try-catch and very simple.

Comment: It may throw an exception as well in case there is more than one thread in use (lets be honest, almost all systems are multithreaded). Entity may be deleted by some other thread after 'if' statement.

Comment: This solution will eventually throw EmptyResultDataAccessException.

Comment: @MichałChilczuk What if this whole code block was enclosed in a `@Transactional` annotation? It surely will run in a same thread right? Then there should not be this exception

Comment: @theprogrammer Probably it will run on the same thread but it is not the case. This code block may be run concurrently even on single threaded system and `@Transactional` does not create any thread synchronization by default (afaik). Probably some pessimistic locking should be added.

Answer (score 1):

use

`repository.deleteAllByIdInBatch(ids);`

it's working in the same way as

`repository.deleteAllById(ids);`

but without throwing exception it an `id` is absent in the db

Answer (score 0):

Override the method :

```
@Transactional
@Override
    public void delete(ID id) {
        T entity = findOne(id);
        if (entity == null) {
          //do something instead of throwing exception ex:
          //syso entity does not exist ; return;
        }
        em.remove(em.merge(entity));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @SQLDelete annotation to override default Hibernate DELETE method and to suppress Exception throwing:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "mytable")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@SQLDelete(
        sql =
        "DELETE FROM mytable " +
        "WHERE my_id = ?"
)
public class MyTable {
  @javax.persistence.Column(name = "my_id", nullable = false)
  @Id
  private Long id;
...
}
```

then hibernate automatically substitutes the '?' in prepared statement with actual id of MyTable object, which is mapped to SQL field 'my_id' of table

In this case no exception will be thrown if the record in table does not exist, only silently deletes 0 rows, as in plain SQL DELETE query

Answer (score 0):

I used bellow method to throw meaningful exception if the entity was not found.

```
if (postsRepository.existsById(postId)) {
    throw new EntityNotFoundExceptionById("Invlaid Id was provided");
}

postsRepository.deleteById(postId);
```

EntityNotFoundExceptionById Class

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionById extends RuntimeException {

    public EntityNotFoundExceptionById(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: We should not throw not found exception when the id not found, since there maybe a cheat to check whether this ID exists in your information system or not. That's not safe.

Comment: What do you mean by a cheat?  existsById needs to be implemented in the CrudRepository. How come it is a cheat?

Comment: agreed that the existsById  from CrudRepository, but when we use it and throw pur own defined the EntityNotFoundExceptionById, that's programmatically unsafe.

Comment: But this code isn't good. You are throwing EntityNotFoundExceptionById if the entity is found, which is a wrong business logic. At the other hand you didn't add anything to the original question, just used other's code solution and wrapped into an exception handler (which wasn't asked).

Answer (score -1):

If you just have to delete with a single Id you can do it this way.

```
if(repsoitory.existsById(id)){ 
   repository.deleteById(id)
}
```

If you have a list of ids to delete what you can do is with java 8

```
 List<Long> ids=new ArrayList<>();
  ids.stream().filter(id->repository.existsById(id))
              .forEach(id->repository.deleteById(id));
```

Comment: You didn't add anything more here compared to other solution. Just a bulk delete solution which was not asked.