# Delete Mapping Exception in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Hello i would like to throw an exception in case the user enters an id that is not existing in the system.
This is my mapping

```java
    @DeleteMapping("/drugs/{neo4jId}")
        public void deleteDrug(@PathVariable Long neo4jId) {
        drugsRep.deleteById(neo4jId);
    }
```

what would you suggest?
* I dont want to handle it only in my Frontend

Comment: What you actually want is exactly here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785622/how-to-i-tell-a-springdata-repositorys-delete-method-to-not-throw-an-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```java
if (drugsRep.existsById(neo4jId)) {
    throw new EntityNotFoundExceptionById("Invlaid Id was provided");
}

drugsRep.deleteById(neo4jId);
```

If you define a custom exception you can map it to appropriate http status.

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionById extends RuntimeException {

    public EntityNotFoundExceptionById(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, in this case you can check if user exists.

In Spring-mongodb have one function when you extends the MongoRepository with the name of existsById. So take a look in the documentation, maybe your repository have this function too.

And, when you use this function you can throw one exception. Like the code

```
if(!repository.existsById(id)){
  throw new NotFoundException();
}

repository.deleteById(id);
```